# How to pin report into dashboard using Power BI Embedded

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want my end user (i.e. non-PowerBI user) to create a dashboard from report using PowerBI embedded.

Currently I am able to authenticate and view existing dashboard using embedded PowerBI for non-PowerBI user but I am not able to pin the report to dashboard.

Please provide some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Pin to dashboard is a feature that is not yet supported in Power BI Embedded.
If you'd like to upvote this feature request, you are welcome to turn to the Power BI Community and express your feature needs in https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas